# Run Node.js & Meteor behind SOCKS proxy

Tags: node.js, meteor, proxy, npm

I am connecting to the internet in country where many sites blocked. So the method of connection is:

`ssh -D 3030 root@46.101.111.333`

then I configured in the Network Preferences

[image]

this way I able to connect anywhere using my browser. No problem. But when I want to install NPM modules or Meteor.js plugins with Terminal I get an error.

in NPM:

> errno: 'ECONNREFUSED' If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

in METEOR:

> Unable to update package catalog (are you offline?)
>
> If you are using Meteor behind a proxy, set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY
>   environment variables or see this page for more details:
>   https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Meteor-behind-a-proxy

---

I followed both Meteor & NPM documentations.

Meteor

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://root:password@46.101.111.333:3030
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://root:password@46.101.111.333:3030
meteor update
```

NPM

```
npm config set proxy http://root:password@46.101.111.333:3030
npm config set https-proxy http://root:password@46.101.111.333:3030
```

and some others...

Please help, what do I need to do else.. Is it ssh or proxy specific issue. Are my settings correct ?

Comment: Perhaps you need to convert the http proxy calls to socks5, see http://superuser.com/questions/423563/convert-http-requests-to-socks5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose your SOCKS5 proxy is: `127.0.0.1:3030` ...

- Install `proxychains-ng` by homebrew
- Create a `~/.proxychains/proxychains.conf`

for example, you may need to add one line:

`socks5   127.0.0.1 3030`

following `[ProxyList]`:

```
# proxychains.conf  VER 4
#
#        HTTP, SOCKS4, SOCKS5 tunneling proxifier with DNS.
#   

# The option below identifies how the ProxyList is treated.
# only one option should be uncommented at time,
# otherwise the last appearing option will be accepted
#
#dynamic_chain
#
# Dynamic - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# at least one proxy must be online to play in chain
# (dead proxies are skipped)
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
strict_chain
#
# Strict - Each connection will be done via chained proxies
# all proxies chained in the order as they appear in the list
# all proxies must be online to play in chain
# otherwise EINTR is returned to the app
#
#random_chain
#
# Random - Each connection will be done via random proxy
# (or proxy chain, see  chain_len) from the list.
# this option is good to test your IDS :)

# Make sense only if random_chain
#chain_len = 2

# Quiet mode (no output from library)
#quiet_mode

# Proxy DNS requests - no leak for DNS data
proxy_dns 

# set the class A subnet number to usefor use of the internal remote DNS mapping
# we use the reserved 224.x.x.x range by default,
# if the proxified app does a DNS request, we will return an IP from that range.
# on further accesses to this ip we will send the saved DNS name to the proxy.
# in case some control-freak app checks the returned ip, and denies to 
# connect, you can use another subnet, e.g. 10.x.x.x or 127.x.x.x.
# of course you should make sure that the proxified app does not need
# *real* access to this subnet. 
# i.e. dont use the same subnet then in the localnet section
#remote_dns_subnet 127 
#remote_dns_subnet 10
remote_dns_subnet 224

# Some timeouts in milliseconds
tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 8000

# By default enable localnet for loopback address ranges
# RFC5735 Loopback address range
localnet 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0
# RFC1918 Private Address Ranges
# localnet 10.0.0.0/255.0.0.0
# localnet 172.16.0.0/255.240.0.0
# localnet 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0


# Example for localnet exclusion
## Exclude connections to 192.168.1.0/24 with port 80
# localnet 192.168.1.0:80/255.255.255.0

## Exclude connections to 192.168.100.0/24
# localnet 192.168.100.0/255.255.255.0

## Exclude connections to ANYwhere with port 80
# localnet 0.0.0.0:80/0.0.0.0

# ProxyList format
#       type  host  port [user pass]
#       (values separated by 'tab' or 'blank')
#
#
#        Examples:
#
#               socks5  192.168.67.78   1080    lamer   secret
#       http    192.168.89.3    8080    justu   hidden
#       socks4  192.168.1.49    1080
#           http    192.168.39.93   8080    
#       
#
#       proxy types: http, socks4, socks5
#        ( auth types supported: "basic"-http  "user/pass"-socks )
#
[ProxyList]
# add proxy here ...
# meanwile
# defaults set to "tor"
socks5  127.0.0.1 3030
```

then run the `meteor` by adding `proxychains4` in front, e.g.:

```
proxychains4 meteor add angularui:angular-ui-router
```